# Create sound manager array for multiple use

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I'm trying to create audio manager so I can easily add audio sounds effects to whatever script I want. I've got 3 scrips , one who is sitting on an empty game object (SoundManager) another that unmono script who just have the data of the audio I want to change, and the third one is the script whom I'm trying to apply the AudioSource to it (right now its just my character attack)
I've been trying to do with some tutorials I found on net. most of them use "Find"  component which I know not the best way of using those. and I'm trying not to make the Audio source component to show on the Sound Manager Gameobject, im trying to create it on the specific char I want using the SoundManager Array ref.

SoundData Script

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Sound{


public string name;
public AudioClip clip;

[HideInInspector]
public AudioSource source;

public bool loop;
public bool playOnstart;

[Range(0f,1f)]
public int spatialBlend;

public int minDistance;
public int maxDistance;
public AudioRolloffMode audioMode;
}
```

SoundManager Script

```
 using UnityEngine.Audio;
 using UnityEngine;
 using System;

public class SoundManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public Sound[] sounds;
 //  public AudioSource audioSource;


private void Awake()
{
    foreach (Sound s in sounds)
    {
       
       //     audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            //s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.source.clip = s.clip;
            s.source.playOnAwake = s.playOnstart;
            s.source.loop = s.loop;
            s.source.spatialBlend = s.spatialBlend;
            s.source.minDistance = s.minDistance;
            s.source.maxDistance = s.maxDistance;
            s.source.rolloffMode = s.audioMode;
        

  
    }
}

public void Play()
{
    //right now i dont have anything that workd


    
}
```

}

at the third script whom im trying to refrence Soundmanager and trying to Getcommponent Audio Script but its gives me NullArgumant most of the times

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to refer to AudioSource component in the beginning of your second script, what I believe is happening here is that Unity can't find a gameObject to attach the AudioSource component to. So to fix this you can use:

In your SoundData script;

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Sound{


public string name;
public AudioClip clip;

[HideInInspector]
// Took out the AudioSource = source; instead...
// ...used a GameObject so we can add the component.
public GameObject sourceGameObject;

public bool loop;
public bool playOnstart;

[Range(0f,1f)]
public int spatialBlend;

public int minDistance;
public int maxDistance;
public AudioRolloffMode audioMode;
```

In your SoundManager script.

```
public Sound[] sounds;

void Awake(){
    foreach (Sound s in sounds){
        s.sourceGameObject = someGameObject;
        AudioSource audioSource = s.sourceGameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        // rest of your code.
    }
}
```

You can write the rest of your code making use of the audioSource variable instead.

Hope this fixes your problem.